# Multiple divs collapse: close one element if other is open (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, togglebutton

HTML

```
<ul id="slider">
<li>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g1"><img src="BLAHBLAH" /></a>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g2"><img src="BLAHBLAH" style="margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px" /></a>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g3"><img src="BLAHBLAH" /></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g4"><img src="BLAHBLAH" /></a>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g5"><img src="BLAHBLAH" style="margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px" /></a>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g6"><img src="BLAHBLAH" /></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g7"><img src="BLAHBLAH" /></a>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g8"><img src="BLAHBLAH" style="margin-left:30px;margin-right:30px" /></a>
    <a class="toggle" href="#g9"><img src="BLAHBLAH" /></a>
</li>
</ul>

<div id="g1" class="gallery"><p>gallery 1</p></div>
<div id="g2" class="gallery"><p>gallery 2</p></div>
<div id="g3" class="gallery"><p>gallery 3</p></div>
...
```

JS:

```
<script>
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    var $toggled = $(this).attr('href');
    $($toggled).siblings(':visible').hide("slide", {direction: 'up'}, 750);
    $($toggled).toggle("slide", {direction: 'up'}, 750);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.GALLERY { display: none; padding: 50px 20px 20px 20px; }
</style>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdrVG/

As title says, how can I close one element if other toggle is clicked?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: How about including jQuery UI when using UI features ? -> http://jsfiddle.net/jdrVG/1/

Comment: Whooops! -.- eheh
Thanks! It's happening a weird thing anyway.. I'm using this live here: http://www.rendezvousroma.it/new/privati.php (at the footer). If you click on one image in the slider all the div disappears while the toggled panel should be open and closed only if I click on another image... what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VHQky/1/)

```
 $($toggled).siblings(':visible').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) yeah with this I can use it without jQuery UI. What should I change to have the .gallery elements removed when a new div is toggled (instead of the togglers)? I updated the question with new markup (reflecting live example I'm using at http://www.rendezvousroma.it/new/privati.php).

Comment: You can use .hide() to hide and reuse, otherwise you can directly use .remove() to remove the element, but removing an element will not show that element again until refresh.

Comment: Uhm.. but why all the div disappears instead of only the toggled divs on my link?

Comment: Thats the question i think, opening one element will hide all other elements.

Comment: it should hide all .gallery elements, not the whole <ul id="slider">.

Comment: you can filter what element you are hiding 
$($toggled).siblings('.galery:visible').hide();